# Postgresql: invalid input syntax for integer: "false"

Tags: postgresql

Below is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE configurations
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  key text,
  description text,
  value text,
  CONSTRAINT configurations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I am inserting data with below query

```
insert into configurations
(id, key, description, value)
select 1,'key1','D1',25
UNION
select 2,'key2','D2',365
UNION
select 3,'key3','D3','2017-01-01'
```

But i am getting below error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2017-01-01"
LINE 7: select 3,'key3','D3','2017-01-01'
```

I don't know why i am getting this error. value "2017-01-01" is a text value and column data type is also text then why i am getting integer specific error.

Answer (score 2):

The `UNION` result set data types will be determined by the logic that favours values that are not string literals -- it is described [in detail in the manual,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html) also note that, without an explicit type specification, string literals are treated as being of type `unknown`.

Specifically, these rules apply in your case:

> 5. Choose the first non-unknown input type which is a preferred type in
> that category, if there is one.

and

> 7. Convert all inputs to the selected type. Fail if there is not a conversion from a given input to the selected type.

This basically means that if you have at least one numeric literal value in a particular column  (in your case fourth)  in your `UNION`ised query, Postgres will attempt to coerce the values in the same column in other `SELECT`s into a number, which obviously fails for the character value `'2017-01-01'`.

Subsequently, if you have at least one character value in that column that cannot be cast into a number, you will have to use explicit character values for the fourth column in **all** `SELECT`s:

```
insert into configurations
(id, key, description, value)
select 1,'key1','D1', '25'
UNION
select 2,'key2','D2', '365'
UNION
select 3,'key3','D3','2017-01-01'
```

H/T to Andriy M for his comment that prompted me to read the manual more thoroughly.